# Related data model in Power Pivot

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have about 4 data tables in my data model with each table related linearly. What I mean is that Table 1 is related to table 2, table 2 to table 3 etc.
How can I access the related data in table 3 from table 1?
I have attempted to add the required column to table 2 and back to table 1, unfortunately, it's not accessible. I can only see the content of table 2 in table 3 and not the other way round.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post an image of your data model - it's hard to understand your problem without seeing your tables and their relations.

Comment: @RADO Here's the link to the requested picture, I couldn't upload directly here.

My intention is to access data in the 4th table from the first table, unfortunately, they are not directly relatable.
I will appreciate any guidance that can be helpful to achieve my objectives.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see your link

Answer (score 0):

If I start with these four tables, named Table1 through Table4, respectively:

[image]

And they are related like this:

[image]
[image]

Then it looks like just using `RELATED(Table[Table3-Entry])` works to get the values from Table3 while starting from Table1:

[image]